# Automatically increase comment karma on comment save

Tags: comments

I don't know why, but it seems like the comment karma column is not used very much in plugins or otherwise.  What would I need to do to hook into adding points to the comments karma column when a logged in user saves a comment?

Comment: What have you tried? The plugins API pages show a list [of hooks for comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions).

Answer (score 1):

The `comment_karma` field in the `wp_comments` table is something that has been in present in WordPress for a long time, but never utilized by the WordPress core itself.

You can update it the same way any other comment field is updated, using [`update_comment()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_comment):

```
$comment_data = array();
$comment_data['comment_ID'] = 1;
$comment_data['comment_karma'] = 123;
wp_update_comment( $comment_data );
```